# Assigning range of values to unknowns in an inequation

Tags: inequality, linear-programming

I am trying to calculate weights to use for a program that is using a minimax tree to search the best possible move for a board game.

I have a bunch of inequations that need to evaluate to true, each having 4 unknown values in them. One of these inequations look something like this:

`25x - 3y - 5z + 3w > 29x - 1y - 7z + 2w`

`x`, `y`, `z`, and `w` are all the changing values in my formula, and I can write out multiple different inequations like this, which should evaluate to true for me.

Is it possible, to find the value (or a range of values) of all unknowns in these inequations? If yes, how is this achieved?

Comment: I take it that you are asking if the variables have bounded ranges.  If so, the answer is "No." In general, you can substitute any real value for $x,$ say, and find values of the the other values that with satisfy the inequality.

Comment: @saulspatz and what if I have multiple inequalities that I want to evaluate to true? Can I find a value for `x`, `y`,`z` and `w` with certainty, with which all the inequalities are true?

Comment: You are asking about the feasible region of a system of linear inequalities.  In general, this is not so easy to find.  (Theoretically, there's no problem, but computation is another matter.)  You can google "linear programming" to find out more about this.